# JACK on Windows: outputting to a virtual microphone?

Tags: windows, jackd

I've been messing about with [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) as it seems like a good way to apply some EQ and whatnot for voice communications. I've gotten it to work, but I can't figure out how to make it output to [Discord](https://discordapp.com/). Some googling basically tells me that Discord doesn't work directly with JACK, so I was thinking the sensible (and most compatible with other programs) solution would be to try to have JACK send its output to a virtual microphone so that that could be used for Discord. However, I can't figure out any method of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried a virtual audio cable? I use jack with ladish on linux to stream to teamspeak without issue.

Comment: That did it, eventually! I originally tried [Virtual Audio Streaming](http://www.virtualaudiostreaming.net/) (Warning: adware bundled in installer; also shareware), but it does not appear to function that well with anything but default devices, which means you'd have to listen to yourself to be able to use it. I found [Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/) today however, and it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/) did the trick, albeit it doesn't integrate with JACK. You can nevertheless use it as you would with any other output device, and this output device outputs to a virtual microphone which can be used for voice chat, recording, etc.